# Page navigation custom

Tags: php

My search result page displays 20 rows per page. I tried to create a way to navigate pages if there is more than 20 rows in the search result using session variables. My problem is that my navigation variable seemingly becomes empty after the first run even though it should be getting a value upon submission since I'm just getting the value of the submit button. It's not displaying any error and from how I understood it it should work so I would like to ask for some help on where my logic seems to be going wrong. Here's the code:

View page:

```
if(isset($pageCount)){      //it has more than one page
        if($pageCount == $currentPage && $pageCount > 1){   //currently at last page
            echo "<form name='searchCompanyFiles'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/search_info/searchCompany' method = POST>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'filter' value = '".$filter."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'searchQuery' value = '".$searchQuery."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'pageCount' value = '".$pageCount."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'currentPage' value = '".$currentPage."'/>
                <input type = 'submit' name = 'navigation' value = 'Prev'/>
            </form>";
        }

        else if($pageCount == $currentPage){                //assuming one page only

        }

        else if($pageCount > 1 && $currentPage > 1){        //somewhere in the middle
            echo "<form name='searchCompanyFiles'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/search_info/searchCompany' method = POST>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'filter' value = '".$filter."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'searchQuery' value = '".$searchQuery."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'pageCount' value = '".$pageCount."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'currentPage' value = '".$currentPage."'/>
                <input type = 'submit' name = 'navigation' value = 'Prev'/>
                <input type = 'submit' name = 'navigation' value = 'Next'/>
            </form>";
    /*      echo "<form name='searchCompanyFiles'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/search_info/searchCompany' method = POST>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'filter' value = '".$filter."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'searchQuery' value = '".$searchQuery."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'pageCount' value = '".$pageCount."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'currentPage' value = '".$currentPage."'/>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'navigation' value = 'next'/>
                <input type = 'submit' value = 'Next'/>
            </form>";*/
        }
        else if($pageCount > 1 && $currentPage == 1){   //currently at first page
            echo "<form name='searchCompanyFiles' class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/search_info/searchCompany' method = POST>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'filter' value = '".$filter."'/>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'searchQuery' value = '".$searchQuery."'/>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'pageCount' value = '".$pageCount."'/>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'currentPage' value = '".$currentPage."'/>
                    <input type = 'submit' name = 'navigation' value = 'Next'/>
            </form>";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "Page count not updating";
    }
```

controller code:

```
if(isset($navigation)){         
            $navigation = $_POST['navigation'];         //after initial search to determine if user
        }                                               //went forward of back
        else{
            echo "SEARCH";
            $navigation = '';
        }
        $pageCount = $_POST['pageCount'];           //
        $currentPage = $_POST['currentPage'];

        $searchQuery = trim($_POST['searchQuery']);
        $filter = $_POST['filter'];

        if(empty($searchQuery)){
            $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchAllCompany($navigation, $pageCount, $currentPage);
        }

        else{
            switch($filter){
                case 1: 
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('searchQuery', 'Search Query', 'is_natural');
                        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                            $_SESSION['fail'] = 'Failed Search';
                        }
                        else{
                            $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchCompanyId($searchQuery);

                        }

                        break;
                case 2: $this->form_validation->set_rules('searchQuery', 'Search Query', 'callback_alpha_dash_space');
                        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                            $_SESSION['fail'] = 'Failed Search';
                        }
                        else{
                            $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchCompanyName($searchQuery);
                        }
                        break;
                case 3: $this->form_validation->set_rules('searchQuery', 'Search Query', 'callback_alpha_dash_space');
                        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                            $_SESSION['fail'] = 'Failed Search';
                        }
                        else{
                            $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchCompanyAcronym($searchQuery);
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                        $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchAllCompany($navigation, $pageCount, $currentPage);

                        // $data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchAllCompany();
                        break;
            }
```

Model Code:

```
$rowsC[] = array();

        if(!empty($pageCount)){     //if there is something to navigate through
            //unset($_SESSION['pageCount']);
            $start = $currentPage * 20;     
            $count = $this->db->query("SELECT * from company ORDER BY id"); 
            $output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from company ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, 20");
            if(strcmp(trim($navigation), "Prev") == 0){
                echo "DID IT ENTER HERE?";
                $currentPage--;
            }else if(strcmp(trim($navigation), "Next") == 0){
                echo "IT ENTERED HERE!";
                $currentPage++;
            }
            echo "Value of navigation: ".$navigation;

                    //update current page
        /*  if($output->num_rows()%20 == 0){
                $_SESSION['pageCount'] = (int)$count->num_rows()/20;        //even count
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['pageCount'] = (int)($count->num_rows()/20) + 1;  //odd count
            }*/
        }
        else{   //initial search

        $count = $this->db->query("SELECT * from company ORDER BY id");
        $output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from company ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 20");

        $currentPage = 1;
            if($count->num_rows()%20 == 0){
                $pageCount = (int)$count->num_rows()/20;        //even count
            }
            else{
                $pageCount = (int)($count->num_rows()/20) + 1;  //odd count
            }
        }
        $i = 0;

        if ($output->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($output->result_array() as $rowC){
                $rowsC[$i]['id'] = $rowC['id'];
                $rowsC[$i]['name'] = $rowC['name'];
                $rowsC[$i]['address'] = $rowC['address'];
                $rowsC[$i]['telNum'] = $rowC['telNum'];
                $rowsC[$i]['faxNum'] = $rowC['faxNum'];
                $rowsC[$i]['email'] = $rowC['email'];
                $rowsC[$i]['website'] = $rowC['website'];
                $rowsC[$i]['acronym'] = $rowC['acronym'];
                $i++;
            }
            return $rowsC;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Ok...I noticed that for some reason the isset($_SESSION['pageCount']) always returns false...why though since I did update it's value in the model code

Comment: you are not utilizing the framework components, you should use http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: wow, whats the use of a framework, if you wont use its components? try to use the pagination class and url segments for this type of task.

Comment: because my URL isn't changing...the example pagination class determines its page based on URL

Comment: and it seems it is actually doable without using sessions though I'm having trouble with the hidden variables I'm passing because for some reason the value of the variable is not going into any of my conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the cause of why I did not get a navigation value

```
if(isset($navigation)){         
            $navigation = $_POST['navigation'];        
}
```

It should've been like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['navigation'])){         
            $navigation = $_POST['navigation'];        
}
```